# JS/jquery hiding content in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a 'best practice' how to hide all except one content-DIV of an HTML5 website?
Is there also a 'most used' library/libraries? Or is it often written in own JS code?

My goal is to have 9 DIVs loaded. The one in the center is the navigation, the others are content. When a nav-point is selected the specific div 'slides' to the middle and all the other DIVs are hidden.

Thank you

Comment: _"Is there also a 'most used' library/libraries?"_ - Well jQuery is used a _lot_ precisely because it makes this sort of thing trivial, but there are other options. Writing it from scratch in "plain" JS wouldn't be particularly difficult either. Given you tagged your question with "jquery" are you asking whether there is a better library for this purpose?

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot for the help!! It works :-) About my 'jquery' question, I was just wondering if there is a dedicated library for this kind of implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a class to all the hide and show able divs probably a class name like section.

```
<div class="section" id="home"> home content here... </div>
<div class="section" id="page-slug"> another page here... </div>
<div class="section" id="contact"> contact information here... </div>
```

Then give each div an id. FInally, in order to show the contact section you would:

```
$('#contact').show().siblings('.section').hide();
```

This method of giving like elements the same `class`and giving container elements an `id` is really just good practice regardless of the ease of use when selecting jQuery elements.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
$('.your_div').show().siblings().hide();
```

Replace `.show()` and `.hide()` with your desired effects.

Comment: +1 `siblings()` is great but it might be too broad a selector in his use case.

Comment: Maybe `.siblings('.your_div')` would be better?

Comment: I like that. Add it. I can't think of a reason the sections would have different parentage. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) are good enough.